# PyCharm не видит модуль airogram (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram')

Tags: python, aiogram, pycharm

Почему-то python не видит модуль airogram. Что имею airogram, переустанавливаемый несколько раз, виртуальное окружение (работаю в PyCharm, а на сколько мне известно оно там встроено), Python 3.10
Ниже прилагаю код бота (если нужно)

```
import logging
import strings
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

API_TOKEN = strings.token


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, теперь я пишусь на Aiogram!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Решение проблемы в интернете найти не смог, везде советуют (пере)установить airogram, что я и делал, но результата нет. Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Может быть такое, что у тебя две версии питона и ты устанавливаешь просто aiogram на Python 3.9, а у тебя Python 3.10. Рекомендую установить через PyCharm пакет, если и это не поможет, то установи через команду:

```
python3.* -m pip install aiogram
```

Comment: Устанавливал через PyCharm, использовал рекомендуемую вами команду, увы, не помогло(

Comment: Вы запускаете код через PyCharm или или через CMD попробуйте и так и так