# ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'aiogram.contrib'

Tags: python, aiogram

Ошибка:

```
**Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'aiogram.contrib'
File "X:\Desktop\valentine-main\valentine-main\bot.py", line 5, in <module>
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram.contrib'**
```

Код:

```
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
...
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())
```

Помогите пожалуйста(((

Comment: Ну, не установил aiogram значит. Или опечатался в импорте. Переустанови aiogram и проверь опечатки в import.

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1447192/pycharm-не-видит-модуль-airogram-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-aiogram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете более новую версию aiogram.

Можете откатиться к более старой версии aiogram<3.0.0

Или использовать:

```
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage
```

И почитать про миграцию [aiogram 2.x -> 3.0](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/migration_2_to_3.html)

Comment: Простите что так поздно принял ответ...

Comment: самый адекватный ответ спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вам стоит обновить aiogram

```
pip install aiogram==3.0.0
```

Comment: Чем этот ответ отличается от предыдущего?