# Termius выдает ошибку No module named 'aiogram.contrib'

Tags: python, aiogram

Хочу задеплоить Telegram бота на aiogram через Termius но выдает ошибку.

```
No module named 'aiogram.contrib'
```

Код импорта:

```py
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
```

В чем может быть проблема? Пробовал запустить через `Pydroid 3` все нормально работает.

Comment: Подозрительно похожий дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1538818/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-aiogram-contrib

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту проблему, откатив *aiogram* до версии, на которой я писал код до обнавления *aiogram*:

```
pip install aiogram==2.25.1
```